software to simulate SQL Server on PostgreSQL
I know about Liberatii software which is a gateway allowing you to use PostgreSQL in the background (or even other engines) without re-writing the application written for Oracle.
Do one of you know if there is a software which works like Liberatii simulating SQL Server with PostgreSQL in the background? We try to find a solution for performance issues and one of the possibilities is a switch to Oracle or Postgres engine, but application modules contain a lot of custom code to be re-written and I evaluate all possible solutions.

Why do you need to simulate SQL Server when you mentioned you use Oracle? Also, your performance problems aren't due to the database system you're using. Switching systems won't magically fix all of your problems. This is a common fallacy.

@J.D. We use SQL Server to host it. I'm aware of the fact, what switching the system doesn't magically solve all my problems. Right now I investigate the possibility to have active-active cluster, in an ideal world it would be an active-active geo-distributed cluster and SQL server doesn't offer any comparable solutions (AG with a RO secondary doesn't help). If you have an idea how I can implement active-active cluster using SQL Server to host ~8TB+ data for 3000 concurrent connections 7x24 mixing OLTP and DWH load, would you please share it with me? It's highly appreciated.

"If you have an idea how I can implement active-active cluster using SQL Server to host ~8TB+ data for 3000 concurrent connections 7x24 mixing OLTP and DWH load, would you please share it with me?" - Sure, the simple solution is to write better queries and architect your system for efficiency. Perhaps a RO secondary would help you by offloading the DWH load. Nothing you described sounds unmanageable. I've worked with similar sized data: individual tables that were multi-terabytes big, 10s of billions of rows, OLTP and OLAP concurrently, on modest servers (4 CPU cores, 16 GB of Memory).

Thank you, but unfortunately it's the 3rd party solution I can't change. I've spent a lot of time with vendor development on the phone, but it simply doesn't work. Last change has "improved" the query from 5 sec to 8 min runtime and we have rolled it back yesterday. Separating OLTP and DWH is only partially possible, because not all application modules allow redirecting to different source. I hope it explains the situation a bit better.

Ahh that's where your mistake is then lol, trying to improve someone else's problem. It's the responsibility of the vendor to fix their crappy software not the customer (which is a dangerous game to play), else risk losing customers. Also, not sure how you'd expect to fix the vendor's software to leverage a different database system, and in an Active-Active environment if they can't even fix their own crappy queries. I don't think your goal to change database systems and environments to be distributed in an Active-Active architecture is realistically possible, unfortunately.

It's even more strange than this. This vendor believes to develop engine-independent software, they do not even test engines and editions, but say "infra is the responsibility of the customer, feel free to design the database environment for this". "You have locking issues because of crappy queries? Some our customers use RCSI. No, our code is not verified to be RCSI ready and we do not use snapshot mode for transactions, but feel free to check if you get any issues using it. No, we do not give any written statement, not our responsibility"... Yes, you are right, it's my mistake LOL

Yea, that's a shitty Vendor, and I'd just straight up nope them and use someone else. I can appreciate that not everyone has that option though. But yea they suck lol. Good luck!

I don't have personal experience with this, but what you're looking for is BabbleFish. It's set up so that, in theory, a front-end application thinks it's talking to SQL Server, but instead it's storing data in PostgreSQL.

Thank you, Grant.

Best of luck. Reading through the comments, this sounds like a real challenge.
